# Need Some Regular Expression Assistance

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to match this data, that is contained in **one** string:

```
vsan 1 interfaces:
fc2/1             
vsan 10 interfaces:
fc1/1             fc1/2             fc1/3             fc1/4             
fc1/5             fc1/6             fc1/7             fc1/8             
fc1/9             fc1/10            fc1/11            fc1/12            
fc1/13            fc1/14            fc1/15            fc1/16
```

The output I am getting is correctly grouped by each vsan, but I am only getting the first interface (fcnn/nn) in each.  For instance, in vsan 10 I want all the interfaces but I am only getting fc1/1.
Here is the Regex I am using:

```
string MemberMatchString = 
    @"vsan\s(?<number>\d+)[\s]interfaces:\n\s+(?<interfaces>\sfc\d+/\d+)\s+\n?";
MatchCollection MemberList = Regex.Matches(block, MemberMatchString);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a simple `String.Split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it tink the best solution would be a Tokenizer/Parser to get the Information you want.

 I don't think you can handle it (efficient and transparent for others) with a single Regex. In my opinion a Regex is not always the Solution for complex string problems.
 I also think, that a large Regex is not maintainable at any time and should therefore  be avoided. (Try it by yourself, get any complex Regex from any Page from the Internet. Don't read, what the expression should do, and try describing the functionality of the expression. You would be supprised what the writer expected, and what you expect the expression to do.
**Simple Regex to bold my point:**

What does this Regex do?

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This Regex is the implementation of the `RFC 2822` from [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) page.

And this one is a reduced one from the same page.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Both can be used to **check a e-mail address**! Did you expect this?

### Solution:

Create a Tokenzier/Parser: So to show you how i would solve this problem I prepared a working sample for you. 
Just Copy paste it to a Console Application, should work fine :-)
Please give me feedback about my code and if my helps was usefull for you.

### Sample explanation:

Create a Tokenizer, which splits the expressions into matching tokens. In this case the Tokens derive from Interface `IToken`.
The Tokens are created by Line and than by a regex Match with groups. See method `Tokenize` and `TokenizeLine`. They do the hard work.

1. Splitting (Line and Spaces)
2. Matching (if Vsan or Interface)

After Splitting it up it gets real simple. Just move forward through the Tokens and create the `VSan` and `Interface` Objects.
The Tokens are order after the order of the String Groups (defined by Regex in Tokenize) so moving through the list is always:

```
VSan
   Interface
   Interface
   Interface

Vsan
   Interface
   Interface
```

So you can easy create a VSan Object and adding all Interfaces afterwards. If the next VSan Token is in line just create a new VsanObject an continue with adding Interfaces to the new Instance.

Now you have a list of Vsans which contains a List of Interfaces which you can use .
I overwrote the `ToString` Method to make the result visible.

### Sample Code:

```
public static class Program{

        static string VsanString = 
@"vsan 1 interfaces:
fc2/1             
vsan 10 interfaces:
fc1/1             fc1/2             fc1/3             fc1/4             
fc1/5             fc1/6             fc1/7             fc1/8             
fc1/9             fc1/10            fc1/11            fc1/12            
fc1/13            fc1/14            fc1/15            fc1/16    ";

        public static void Main (string[] args) {

            VSanTokenizer vSanTokenizer = new VSanTokenizer(VsanString);
            IList<IToken> tokens = vSanTokenizer.Tokens;
            VsanTokenInterpreter vsanTokenInterpreter = new VsanTokenInterpreter(tokens);
            IList<IVSan> vSans = vsanTokenInterpreter.VSans;
            foreach (IVSan vSan in vSans) {
                Console.WriteLine(vSan.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please press return to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    interface IVSan {
        int Number { get; }
        IList<IInterface> Interfaces { get; }
    }

    class VSan : IVSan {
        private readonly IList<IInterface> interfaces;
        private readonly int number;

        public VSan(int number, IList<IInterface> interfaces) {
            this.number = number;
            this.interfaces = interfaces;
        }

        public override string  ToString() {

            StringBuilder toString = new StringBuilder();

            toString.Append("Vsan with Number: ");
            toString.Append(number);
            toString.Append(" has following Interfaces:");
            toString.AppendLine("");

            foreach (IInterface @interface in Interfaces) {
                toString.Append("Intefaces with Name: ");
                toString.Append(@interface.Name);
                toString.AppendLine("");
            }
            return toString.ToString();
        }

        #region Implementation of IVSan

        public int Number {
            get { return number; }
        }

        public IList<IInterface> Interfaces {
            get { return interfaces; }
        }

        #endregion
    }


    interface IInterface {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    class Interface : IInterface {
        private readonly string name;

        public Interface(string name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        #region Implementation of IInterface

        public string Name {
            get { return name; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    interface IToken {
        string Value { get; }
    }

    interface IVsanToken : IToken {
        int VsanInterfaceNumber { get; }
    }

    internal abstract class AbstractToken : IToken {
        private readonly string value;

        public AbstractToken(string value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        #region Implementation of IToken

        public string Value {
            get { return value; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    class VsanToken : AbstractToken, IVsanToken {

        private readonly int vsanInterfaceNumber;

        public VsanToken(string value)
            : base(value) {
            vsanInterfaceNumber = int.Parse(value);
        }

        #region Implementation of IVsanToken

        public int VsanInterfaceNumber {
            get { return vsanInterfaceNumber; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    class InterfaceToken : AbstractToken, IInterfaceToken {

        private readonly int firstNumber;
        private readonly int secondNumber;

        public InterfaceToken(string value)
            : base(value) {

            Match match = Regex.Match(value, "fc([0-9])/([0-9]+)");
            Group firstNumberGroup = match.Groups[1];
            Group secondNumberGroup = match.Groups[2];

            firstNumber = int.Parse(firstNumberGroup.Value);
            secondNumber = int.Parse(secondNumberGroup.Value);
        }

        public int SecondNumber {
            get { return secondNumber; }
        }

        public int FirstNumber {
            get { return firstNumber; }
        }
    }

    interface IInterfaceToken : IToken {
        //Edited: Added Second and FirstNumber to Interface so it can be accessed
        int SecondNumber { get; }

        int FirstNumber { get ; }

    }

    class VSanTokenizer {
        private readonly string vSanString;
        private IList<IToken> tokens;

        public VSanTokenizer(string vSanString) {
            this.vSanString = vSanString;
            tokens = Tokenize(vSanString);
        }

        public string VSanString {
            get { return vSanString; }
        }

        private IList<IToken> Tokenize(string vSanString) {
            List<IToken> tokens = new List<IToken>();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(vSanString);
            string readLine = reader.ReadLine();
            while (readLine != null) {
                IList<IToken> tokenizeLine = TokenizeLine(readLine);
                tokens.AddRange(tokenizeLine);
                readLine = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            return tokens;
        }

        private IList<IToken> TokenizeLine(string readLine) {
            IList<IToken> tokens = new List<IToken>();
            Match vsanInterfaceDeclartion = Regex.Match(readLine, "vsan ([0-9]+) interfaces:");
            if (vsanInterfaceDeclartion.Success) {
                Group numberGroup = vsanInterfaceDeclartion.Groups[1];
                VsanToken vsanToken = new VsanToken(numberGroup.Value);
                tokens.Add(vsanToken);
                return tokens;
            }

            Match vsanInterface = Regex.Match(readLine, "(fc[0-9]/[0-9]+)");
            if (vsanInterface.Success) {
                GroupCollection groupCollection = vsanInterface.Groups;
                foreach (Group vsanInterfaceGroup in groupCollection) {
                    string value = vsanInterfaceGroup.Value;
                    IToken token = new InterfaceToken(value);
                    tokens.Add(token);
                }
            }

            return tokens;
        }

        public IList<IToken> Tokens {
            get {
                return tokens;
            }
        }
    }

    class VsanTokenInterpreter {
        private readonly IList<IToken> tokens;
        private readonly IList<IVSan> vSans;

        public VsanTokenInterpreter(IList<IToken> tokens) {
            this.tokens = tokens;

            this.vSans = ParseTokens(tokens);
        }

        private IList<IVSan> ParseTokens(IList<IToken> tokens) {
            IList<IVSan> vsans = new List<IVSan>();

            IVSan currentVSan = null;
            foreach (IToken token in tokens) {
                if (token is IVsanToken) {
                    currentVSan = CreateVSan((IVsanToken)token);
                    vsans.Add(currentVSan);
                } else if (token is IInterfaceToken) {
                    if (currentVSan == null)
                        throw new Exception("First Vsan Line has to be declared!");
                    IInterface inter = CreateInterface((IInterfaceToken)token);

                    currentVSan.Interfaces.Add(inter);
                }
            }

            return vsans;
        }

        protected virtual IInterface CreateInterface(IInterfaceToken interfaceToken) {
            //Edited: you can now access the First/Second Number from the Interface Token and use it to create the Instance of your interface:

            int firstNumber = interfaceToken.FirstNumber;
            int secondNumber = interfaceToken.SecondNumber;
            return new Interface(interfaceToken.Value);

        }

        protected virtual IVSan CreateVSan(IVsanToken vsanToken) {
            return new VSan(vsanToken.VsanInterfaceNumber, new List<IInterface>());

        }

        public IList<IVSan> VSans {
            get { return vSans; }
        }

        public IList<IToken> Tokens {
            get { return tokens; }
        }
    }
```

### Result and Conclusion:

As a result you get a IVsan which contains the IInterfaces. You can use this Model in your code to get Information you looking for.

1. By using a Object Model you can change the parsing at any time,
   without changing anything in your business logic.
2. The Parsing logic is more simple and understandable than in Regex
3. There are readable Exception possible (for user Input)
4. You can resolve int/bools a.s.o. during transformation
5. Your colleagues can handle and maintain your code.

Please ask me if you have furhter questions, i would be glad helping you! Please also give me feedback, I'm open for new impressions!

Comment: I already have the VSAN implemented as an object.  I also have the interface implemented as an object.  The VSAN contains a list of the interfaces (ports).  This bit is just the code that pulls what I need out of the file to fill the list.                                                                  That being said, thanks for this work.  I can see where you are going with it and I will see if I can implement it in my existing code.   It will also serve as a model moving forward, as there are other sections of the input file with a similar format - data grouped by a keyword.

Comment: Hi Oberfreak, reviewing your code, what is the advantage to the interfaces IVSAN, IInterface, etc for the classes?  I have a VSAN class and an interface (I call it a SwitchPort) class implemented but am wondering about using an Interface?   Just for some background, I am learning C# as a I go.  I have a smattering of Java, VB and some C++ but don't know enough for it to be really useful.  I am also familiar with at least the basic OO concepts.

Comment: Hey David, i try using interfaces as often as possible. Interfaces makes it possible for me to change the implementation in some parts of the code without refactoring the whole program. In this case could implement a Class "VSanLazyLoading" which does the parsingwhen you request it. Your BusinessLogic would take this LazyClass like the old one. In small Projects, this is not verry common, in big ones you can save much time for the different implementations. And it also makes your BusinessLogic reusable. The best reusable Example is IEnumerable which is taken ny nearyl all List implementations!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is a small project, so I think I will skip the interfaces.  I did learn some stuff from your code though, like instead of spltting the string at \n and walking through an array, I can use StringReader to read lines...

Comment: Ok, another question... in the 'foreach' in the ParseTokens method, how do I access the attributes in the token?  When it finds an InterfaceToken, I want to be able to access the Slot and Port numbers but I can't figure out how to do do it.  I tried just token.SlotNum but the compiler didn't know what that was.  Next I tried token.base.SlotNum, the compiler said 'base' was a reserved keyword. I can see in the debuger looking at the locals the token tree there is a base, in the base there is a SlotNum and a PortNum.  I just can't access them.

Comment: Updated my sample Code by Adding FirstNumber and SecondNumber to the IInterfaceToken Interface. If you want to use it in IInterface or in the Interface Class you have to pass it to the constructor if Interface. Where do you need those two information?

Comment: If you want to use it directly in the foreach method you have to cast "token" to IInterfaceToken by using this "IInterfaceToken interToken = (IInterfaceToken)token;" than you can acces "FirstNumber" and "SecondNumber" on "interToken" example: "interToken.FirstNumber"

Comment: Ok, I see the updated code.  That makes sense.  I had tried putting something like that into effect but couldn't quite figure it out.  I already have the switch modeled as an object in other code, including interfaces.  I just needed to get those slot/port numbers so I can use the IList that gets returned to populate my list.  I will also add some other attributes and methods to this code,there are other places in the file with a similiar list of interfaces, just different info there.  I am trying to organize 30+MB text files and only capture the data I need, which is very little.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by *parapura*, I'd use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), at least to retrieve the interfaces:

```
String block = "vsan 10 interfaces:\nfc1/1             fc1/2   fc1/3\nfc1/4";
String number = Regex.Match(block, @"vsan\s(?<number>\d+)\sinterfaces:").
    Groups["number"].Value;
String[] interfaces = block.Substring(block.IndexOf(':') + 2).
    Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

You are only getting the first interface because your regex requests the match to be (simplified):

```
vsan X interfaces:
fcX/X
```

This means that your want `vsan X interfaces:` to appear in front of each `fcX/X`, whereas that's not the case in your string.

Comment: What I want in the end is the interfaces grouped by the VSAN number.  Is there a way to do this with a regular expression?

Comment: What do you call the *VSAN number*?

Comment: in the input, the number after 'vsan', so in this input, 1 or 10.  if I can do this with Regex, then going forward there is other data that follows a similar patter that I could write the regex for.  Plus with the regex then I know that all the data I capture for a particular vsan belongs with it.  I have it written using split already, but that requires additional checks to make sure the data goes with that vsan

Comment: Oh so `vsan 1 interfaces:...` and `vsan 10 interfaces:` are in fact in the *same* string? If so, sorry for editing your post in a wrong way.

Comment: Yes it is all one string.  The input file is a a collection of 'show' commands.  The initial pass through the file reads the lines between each 'show' command and creates a string, then loads that string into an array of strings.  Each string is the output for a given 'show' command.  In this case, the string starts with 'show vsan membership' and this is the output of that.  I know I could search the string for the 'vsan' pattern then start loading a list with the matches and handle it that way, but I'd rather have the regex do it if possible.

Comment: Are you sure you want all the results in a `String[]` or a `List<String>`? If you want results grouped by the *vsan* number, I feel that it's not the right choice. You should maybe think of getting the results in a object like a `Dictionnary<String, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<string> interfaces = new List<string>();
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(subjectString))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"fc\d+/\d+");
            Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(line);
            while (matchResults.Success)
            {
                interfaces.Add(matchResults.Value);
                matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
            } 
        }
    }
    foreach (var inter in interfaces) Console.WriteLine("{0}", inter);
```

Output :

```
fc1/1
fc1/2
fc1/3
fc1/4
fc1/5
fc1/6
fc1/7
fc1/8
fc1/9
fc1/10
fc1/11
fc1/12
fc1/13
fc1/14
fc1/15
fc1/16
```